# Nifi APPLICATION UI is showing blank screen. Flows are not visible for All users/Administrators. But policies are present

Tags: apache-nifi

Nifi APPLICATION UI is showing blank screen. Flows are not visible for  All users/Administrators. But policies are present[image]

Comment: The reason was flowfile got corrupted and  after replacing from the backup the issue got resolved.